# Google Maps coordinates from an imported file, not the database

Tags: json, angular, google-maps, typescript

I have a few JSON arrays of polyLine coordinates I want to display on a google map using angular. Rather than define them in line as shown below, I would like to import the const arrays from another file.

Changes to the coordinates will be extremely rare (they represent the borders of a few U.S. states) and the arrays are not substantial enough IMO to warrant creating a new db table and all the associated plumbing. They are substantial enough to ugly up my code by being defined in ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit() {
const mapOptions = {
  center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
  zoom: 5,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
const myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my-map"), mapOptions);

const flightPlanCoordinates = [
   {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
   {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
   {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
   {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
 ];
const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: flightPlanCoordinates,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
flightPath.setMap(myMap);
```

}

The coordinates above are from Google's documentation, but the principle is the same: I would like flightPlanCoordinates, and other coordinate arrays, to be defined in a separate file which I can import and use in this component. I am having no luck as it seems anything imported from an external .ts file is out of scope at run time. I am simply cut/pasting the array definition into my external .ts file because I'm not sure what other supporting data structures would be needed. I'm still green on Typescript, so I'm certain I'm making a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in my project is export it as const in a separate file:

server.config.ts:

```
export const ServerConfig = {
    apiEndPoint: ....,
    ...
}
```

And then import it in project:

```
import {ServerConfig} from './server.config';
```

Then I can use it:

```
db = ServerConfig.apiEndPoint;
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple! I was missing the `export` before each `const` array I wanted to import. Maybe it will help another newb to know that I imported like this: `import * as borders from './borders';` then I referred to each as `borders.Alaska`, `borders.Alabama`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax call or something similar and put the result in `flightPlanCoordinates` .